# custom java annotations ind javadoc / doxygen

Tags: annotations, javadoc

i have build a custom annotation like

```
    package com.uc4.ucdf.control.xgui;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XGUIElement {

    public String Name();

    public String Description();

    public XGUIAttribute[] Attributes();

    public String CodeSnipet();
}
```

and

```
package com.uc4.ucdf.control.xgui;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XGUIAttribute {

    public String Name();

    public String ValueType();

    public String Description();
}
```

in my class file i get this annotation

```
@XGUIElement(   Name = "dialog", 
                Description = "this component provides a empty internal window with a title and some properties like if its minimizable, maximizable", 
                CodeSnipet = "<dialog id=\"myDialog\" text=\"Hello World\">", 

                Attributes = {
                    @XGUIAttribute(Description = "Set the width of the Dialog", Name = "width", ValueType = "Integer"),
                    @XGUIAttribute(Description = "Set the height of the Dialog", Name = "height", ValueType = "Integer"),
                    @XGUIAttribute(Description = "1 for true; 0 for false", Name = "top", ValueType = "Integer"),
                    @XGUIAttribute(Description = "Set the left position of this dialog", Name = "left", ValueType = "Integer"),
                    @XGUIAttribute(Description = "Allows you to set the dialog over all not ontop dialogs 1 for true; 0 for false ", Name = "ontop", ValueType = "Integer")
                }

)
```

this works create and i can read the single values in my swingComponent
but i should bring this annoation into the javaDoc build with Doxygen.

so why i can't see the annotation in my javadoc und how i can fromated it into a tablelist of all attributes.